# Nonsensical jReddit Build Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Upon building my Android Studio project with jReddit (the Reddit API wrapper), I get an enormous amount of nonsensical errors.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.util.FastMap$EntrySet$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.util.FastMap$KeySet$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.util.FastMap$Values$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sam\AndroidStudioProjects\Greddit\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\jsch-0.1.50_618dfcdc60f70aebfd3b022c4a651c9c6cedb84e\classes.dex (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)
> C:\Users\Sam\AndroidStudioProjects\Greddit\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\jsch-0.1.50_618dfcdc60f70aebfd3b022c4a651c9c6cedb84e\classes.dex (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)
```

The real kicker is the end error, where it says `* What went wrong:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sam\AndroidStudioProjects\Greddit\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\jsch-0.1.50_618dfcdc60f70aebfd3b022c4a651c9c6cedb84e\classes.dex (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)

> C:\Users\Sam\AndroidStudioProjects\Greddit\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\jsch-0.1.50_618dfcdc60f70aebfd3b022c4a651c9c6cedb84e\classes.dex (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)`

Hm. A virus? What could it be talking about? I have scoured the web for any errors of this sort, and only found one from about a year ago with no solutions. I'd really appreciate any help. Just let me know if you need any more files or information.